# Android: SQLiteDatabase size

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using the Android SQLiteDatabase in my application. Part of the application involves downloading a significant amount of data from a server and storing it on the phone's local db. Is there a way to find out how much space the database will actually take on the phone? I can't find any database-related files in the project folder.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The local SQLite database stores in `Environment.getDataDirectory()` + `/data/<Package Name>/databases`. Also you can call *SQLiteDatabase$getPath()* method.

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
// ...
long size = new File(db.getPath()).length();
```

Comment: I couldn't find the actual directory for some reason, but the code above worked. I got somewhere in the order of 1 million. Is it in bytes?

Comment: Yes, the length() method returns file size in bytes (or zero, if file doesn't exist).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Eclipse do this:

1. Run or Debug your project.
2. Open the File Explorer window.
3. Scroll down the main /data directory until you find your package/databases/ (com.blabblah.appname/databases/) folder.

You will see your database in this directory. If you want to pull the DB from your phone, use the buttons at the top of the File Explorer window, the first button pulls a file from your device, the second button allows you to put a file on your device and the last button deletes the selected file.

I often grab my DB from my app in this regard and do some "offline" testing in SQLite clients, it's very handy.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks so much. For some reason I couldn't find the actual databases or data directory (looked all over my Eclipse project folder and nowhere to be found). I've been looking in workspace/project_name/*. Any idea where else it can be?

Comment: You're using the wrong window, you're probably using the Project Explorer and not the File Explorer. The Project Explorer will just show you the package folders, it won't show you the local folders the package stores data in. For that, you need to use the File Explorer as mentioned above :) Also, if you haven't created your DB, it won't be the data/package/databases folder, I know it seems obvious, but make sure your DB is being created successfully (when you make it into the right window in Eclipse).